# How to split full name from view into first_name and last_name and send to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, model

I have a form input field in my view where i choose to capture a users name with just one input field:

```
  _signup_form.html.erb

  <div class="row">
    <%= form_for @user, class: "form", id: "subscribe-form", role: "form" do |u| %>
    <div class="line">
      <%= u.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name here...', class: 'form-control', required: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <%= u.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Your email here...', class: 'form-control', required: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <%= u.submit 'Notify me', class: 'btn btn-danger btn-fill' %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Currently I just save the name variable, which will include both the users first and last name, to the model:

```
  users_controller.rb

  def create
    @user = User.create(params[:user].permit(:name, :email))

    if @user.save
      redirect_to user_path(@user), :notice => 'You have been registered'
    else
      render '/users/new'
    end
  end
```

But i'd now like to save not the entire `user.name` field to the model, but to split it and send `user.first_name` and `user.last_name` to the model. I understand how to write the .split methods:

```
  users_helper.rb

  def first_name(name)
    name.split(' ')[0].capitalize
  end

  def last_name(name)
    name.split(' ')[1].capitalize
  end
```

And i have done my `bin/rails g migrate add_first_name_to...` and migrated to create the model attributes, but i'm unsure how to integrate #first_name and #last_name methods into the controller to then send each off to the model. A) Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to do this and B) Is this best practice? (reason I'm only offering name field, as opposed to first_name and last_name fields in the view is as i thought it just represent's a nicer experience for a user to put it in one field, ie no tabbing or cursor click into last_name input). Thanks

Comment: This is a risky manoeuvre - what will you do with `'Sarah Jessica Parker'` or`'Felix Mendelsohn Bartholdy`?

Comment: I guess I'll write methods to capture those cases and the anything after the first ' ' will be stored in last_name. Any suggestions as to a better way to do things then?

Comment: Why you don't take the simplest way and put two input fields? Why you make this tight limit? I do not think that you can find a way to guess the first and last names from a name, there is no standard for this.

Comment: Because i felt that having one field for name gives a nicer ux than having two fields that's all. I feel like a fair few contemporary apps do this same thing no?

Comment: Please don't split names into first and last name. If you absolutely have to ask the user what they think makes most sense to use as first or last name. And do not be surprised that many people do not even have a first or last name. I suggest to read: [Falsehoods Programmers beliee about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: What if your guys come from China or Japan, where their names don't have spaces in between?

Comment: @jbk Form follows function. A nicer UX does not trump a useful application in the same way that a pretty and colorful decal applied over my entire windshield does not trump my need to see the road and traffic. TL;DR: Do what works first, then make it pretty.

Comment: Ha ha ha, off to buy a colourful decal for my entire windshield right now ;)

Comment: Thanks for thoughts and comments all.